# An issue with variable expansion. Get a variable into the name of the variable to echo

Tags: bash, shell, variables, expansion

I'd really appreciate help with this. I have 3 strings and I want to echo one of them randomly.

```
INTRO0="Welcome to Foo"
INTRO1="Foo welcomes you"
INTRO2="We are glad to see you at Foo"

R=$((RANDOM%3))

echo $INTRO${R}
```

I expect it to expand the value of R so it'll interpret it as e.g. echo $INTRO1

I've made it work with if statements where it checks the value of R and prints the appropriate INTRO, but if I had 10 strings it would get messy with if statements. Is it possible to do it this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bash:

```
intro_r=INTRO$R
echo ${!intro_r}
```

But I would use a single array `intro` instead of three individual variables `INTRO1` and so on:

```
intro=( "..." "..." "..." )
echo ${intro[$R]}
```